# C++: Inheritance from template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, struct

In the next code example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f() {
    return 0;
}
struct A {
    int f()    {
        return 1; }
};
template<class T>
struct C : public T {
    C() {
        cout << f() << endl;
    } };
int main() {
    C<A> c; // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

If I change the inheritance to be non-template like this:
`struct C : public A`

then it prints "1" and not 0.

Why is that?

Comment: [Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in `f()`, `f` is a nondependent name, so name lookup happens at template definition time (before `T` is known) and binds it to `::f`. If you want it to call the member function f, then use `this` to make it a dependent name:

```
template<class T>
struct C : public T {
    C() {
        cout << this->f() << endl;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Alternatively, `T::f()`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I'd go with `this->` as the general advice, since `T::f()` will disable dynamic dispatch (if the function was virtual)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: In this context (constructor), dynamic dispatch is disabled anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @Nemo: Dynamic dispatch is not disabled in the constructor, it will just hit the final overrider at this point. In this particular case, that could only be `T` or `C`, if the final overrider was in `C`, then no qualification would be needed... so yes, in this case it does not matter, but I rather recommend the general approach than one limited to just the constructor/destructor. On a different note, if the member is *pure virtual*, it will matter (non-dynamic dispatch will call the definition in `T` if present, dynamic will cause undefined behavior)